# Alignment options for marginpar

Tags: packages, marginpar, marginnote

I'm searching for more powerful annotation library than `marginpar`. In particular, I would like to have the feature to center the annotation vertically in the corresponding paragraph.

`marginnote` seems to be better suited for the case of floating objects. However it lacks of the above feature as well.

I had partial success by wrapping the contents of the paragraph into a `minipage` with center alignment. However, this approach cannot handle page breaks.

Is there a more powerful package than `marginpar` and `marginnote` that features the above requirement?

Comment: There is the [marginfix library](http://ctan.um.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/marginfix/marginfix.pdf), you may give it a try.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163567/margin-notes-multicols-tikz-overlay/163843?s=5|1.0000#163843 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215322/multiple-marginnote-commands-on-the-same-line-in-math-environment/216037?s=21|0.2393#216037