# How to add notes to an artificially created margin?

Tags: tcolorbox, xparse

I am aggregating a [document class for taking Cornell-styled notes](https://gitlab.com/MLNW/cornell-notes-template). For this purpose, I am using the `tcolorbox` package and arrange them into two columns. `terms` on the left and `notes` related to these `terms` on the right. Here is an example:

[image: sample of layout]

Now I would like to add the possibility of highlighting certain parts of the `notes` with text in the "margin" introduced with the `term` column. Something like this:

[image: sample of wanted behavior]

Here is the full class as of right now:

```latex
\ProvidesClass{cornell}
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary
{
    breakable,% Allows tcolorboxes to break across pages
    hooks,% Allows usage of hooks, like having an overlay only for the first part of a broken box
    skins,% Used to style the boxes with tikz
    xparse% Used to define document environments and commands
}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % Change geometry of pages
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Modify parindent and parskip
\usepackage{enumitem} % Modify itemize spacing
\setitemize
{
    itemsep=0pt,
    parsep=2pt,
}

\usepackage{bookmark} % Add bookmarks to the resulting PDF
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup
{
    colorlinks   = true, % Colour links instead of ugly boxes
    urlcolor     = blue, % Colour for external hyperlinks
    linkcolor    = blue, % Colour of internal links
    citecolor    = red   % Colour of citations
}

\date{}

\tcbset
{
    colframe=black,
    colupper=black,
    opacitybacktitle=1,
    opacitytext=1,
    fonttitle=\large\bfseries\sffamily,
}

\NewTColorBox[]{titlebox}{ o }
{
    width=\textwidth,
    lowerbox=invisible,
    bookmark*={level=0}{\@title}
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{
    \vspace{-3em}
    \begin{titlebox}
        \Huge{\sffamily{\@title}}
    \end{titlebox}
}

\NewTColorBox[]{extra}{ m }
{
    width=\textwidth,
    title=#1,
    bookmark*={rellevel=1}{#1},
}

\NewTColorBox[]{term}{ m }
{
    width=.325\textwidth,
}

% A note is a tcolorbox in the right column. It may be associated to a
% term which is provided as an optional argument. If a term is provided
% another left-aligned tcolorbox is created with a bookmark.
% It is also possible to give the note itself a title. In this case the
% note tcolorbox is given the provided title and a bookmark for this
% title is created.
\NewTColorBox[]{note}{ o d<> }
{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    IfValueT={#1}{bookmark*={rellevel=1}{#1}},
    IfValueT={#2}{
        bookmark*={rellevel=2}{#2},
        title=#2,
    },
    enlarge left by=.34\textwidth,
    width=.66\textwidth,
    parbox=false,% restore main text formatting behavior
    overlay unbroken={
        \IfNoValueF{#1} {%
            \node[anchor=north west, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] at ([xshift=-.34\textwidth]frame.north west) {
                \begin{term}{#1}
                    #1
                \end{term}
            };
        }{}
    },
    overlay first app={
        \IfNoValueF{#1} {%
            \node[anchor=north west, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] at ([xshift=-.34\textwidth]frame.north west) {
                \begin{term}{#1}
                    #1
                \end{term}
            };
        }{}
    }
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{summary}{}
{
    \vfill
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        floatplacement=!b,
        float,
        title=Summary,
        bookmark*={level=1}{Summary},
        parbox=false,% restore main text formatting behavior
    ]
}
{
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
```

And here is the sample file:

```latex
\documentclass{cornell}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{A topic we're taking notes on}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{extra}{Introduction}
    This can be used to introduce what is about to come, like
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item{What's the first question this section will answer?}
        \item{What's the second question?}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{extra}

\begin{note}[Some key term]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item{A cool thing}
        \item{Another cool thing}
        \item{Not all things are cool}
    \end{itemize}

    That has another paragraph.
\end{note}

\begin{note}<This is a titled noted with a very long title that should wrap around>
    \lipsum[10]
\end{note}

\begin{summary}
    A fabulous summary.

    With multiple paragraphs.
\end{summary}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A simple `overlayed` and `remembered` node could be used to do that.

Comment: @Ignasi not really sure what you mean by that. Are these `tikz` terms?

Comment: Paracol can handle uneven columns over multiple pages, although \switchcolumn* would not allow you to interrupt a tcolorbox in progress.  You could just leave one column blank and overlay tikzpictures even with the current baseline.  See tikzpagenodes and (current page text area.west).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163567/margin-notes-multicols-tikz-overlay for doing this with normal margins.  IIRC, tcolorbox redefines tikzpicture to allow them inside a tcolorbox.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of `\marginpar` or the `\graffito` command from the `classicthesis` package. See this [image](https://benjaminhopfer.com/assets/2014-04-16-typesetting-thesis-latex/da_fullview.png) for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to move the margin into the text area thus creating the wished effect.
The details can be seen [here](https://gitlab.com/MLNW/cornell-notes-template/-/commit/bc565fcac0529932fed8f7726c55290da076e393).

This is the important part:

```
\usepackage{geometry} % Change geometry of pages
\usepackage{marginnote} % Used to create notes in the margin
\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{} % Align notes to the left
\reversemarginpar
\geometry{
    margin=2cm,
    marginparsep=-.35\textwidth,
    marginparwidth=.325\textwidth,
}
```

The result looks like this:
[image: the result]