# Highlight first occurrence of a reference or reference list in text

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, highlighting

This is a follow-up question. A working example of highlighting the first reference in text can be found in

[Highlight first occurence of reference in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278106/highlight-first-occurence-of-reference-in-text)

However, there is an open question on how to handle lists of references. For now, the answer neglects lists and does not keep track of their occurrence. I require highlighting the complete list and keeping track of the highlights as if the references were standalone. So if I say

```
\cref{eq:1,eq:2,eq:3}
```

I would get highlighted

**Equations (1) to (3)**

If I then reference to one of these equations again, they won't be highlighted as they were already highlighted in the list?

Thanks for your help and a happy new year to you all!

Comment: Off-topic: Using label names such as `eq:1` etc. are not really useful; if the order of equation changes it's sometimes necessary to change the label names here as well. Use human readable label names, such as `\label{eq:einsteinsenergyrelation}` etc.

Comment: Regarding `cleveref`: There is a whole section (or chapter)  about customizing the format (= highlighting) of the references, see section 8 of current [cleveref documentation file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf)

Comment: Hello, the numbers are only an example to shorten the question. I do not find any help in the cleverref documentation for changing the format of the first occurrence. Maybe you can specify the position were I find additional information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make this thing working via xparse and splitlist. I parse the list and set the marginnotes by processing the comma separated list.

Here is the working solution for anyone interested:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{>{\SplitList{,}}m}{{\ProcessList{#1}\myphantom}}
  \newcommand\myphantom[1]{%
  \ifcsname marginnote@#1\endcsname
  \else
  \expandafter\gdef\csname marginnote@#1\endcsname{}}
%Redefine \cref so that it will make a margin note if the passed label is referenced for the first time.
    \let\oldcref=\cref
\def\cref#1{%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{,}{%
      \ifcsname creflnote@#1\endcsname%
        \oldcref{#1}%
      \else
        {\foo{#1}}%
        \myul{2pt}{0.5pt}{1}{\oldcref{#1}}%
        \expandafter\gdef\csname creflnote@#1\endcsname{}%
        \fi
    }{%
    %check if the label has already been referenced.
    \ifcsname marginnote@#1\endcsname
        %already exists...therefore not the first citation
        \oldcref{#1}%
    \else
        \myul{2pt}{0.5pt}{1}{\oldcref{#1}}%}
        \expandafter\gdef\csname marginnote@#1\endcsname{}%first citation...with this defined, will not underline again
    \fi
    }}
\makeatother
```

Have a nice day!